# Inherited Resources: can't get the parent in a polymorphic_belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inherited-resources

I am using Inherited Resources in my Rails application but I have an issue:

I can't access the parent object when I use a polymorphic relation between my controllers.

Following the documentation, I have a controller like this:

```
class PhotosController < InheritedResources::Base
  belongs_to :user, :task, :polymorphic => true

  def index
    logger.debug(parent.inspect)
  end
end
```

But parent always returns nil.
It doesn't work either with:

```
polymorphic_belongs_to :user, :task
```

However, it works if I don't use a polymorphic relation:

```
belongs_to :user
```

or

```
belongs_to :task
```

Note that my routes and everything else regarding inherited_resources work fine.

I am using Rails 2.3.10 and InheritedResources 1.0.6 but some people have the same issue with Rails 3. Here is a post in the mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/inherited_resources/browse_thread/thread/8d154492bad90f2d

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: I have the same problem with `:optional=>true`.